# In which month should I map maritime vegetation?

Tags: ecology, vegetation

I'm studying habitat use by Brent Goose in the UK, a species that feeds on maritime vegetation. It's main food types are *Zostera* sp., *Ruppia* sp., *Ulva* / *Enteromorpha* sp. and *Puccinellia* sp. I plan to map these vegetation types on an inter-tidal mudflat in North-east England during the summer.

I want to choose a month to map these vegetation types that will allow the most accurate mapping of their distribution of vegetation across the mudflat. I think there are two considerations 1. the month they easiest to identify 2. the month they are most visible.

Which month should I choose?

Comment: @kmm. Thanks for edit. What do asterisk around Enteromorpha mean?

Comment: That's just the markup for italics. For some reason the parser didn't like /*. I added spaces around / to make both genera italics.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem would be to look at herbarium collections of the taxa that you're interested in. Usually, a flowering or fruiting specimen is easiest to identify; but no matter what character is best for your taxon, if you look at the herbarium collections and see that
-most of the collections identified to species, or 
-the especially good-looking collections, or 
-flowering/fruiting collections, 
were made in a certain month or season, that could help you to narrow down your time window.

As a bonus, in reviewing herbarium collections, you'll have given yourself a step towards being able to identify the species.

Some herbaria have some collections online; here, for instance, are [records and images for online *Puccinellia* collections](http://herbariaunited.org/specimensearch/?taxon=Puccinellia&taxonid=8072&collector=&colid=&role=prov&from=&to=&search=search&Country=gbie&VC=all&place=&placeid=&Inst=all&search=search#searchlist) at a number of UK herbaria.